# How do I increase /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max to more than 8192?

Tags: ubuntu, c

Is it possible to change the default value to be larger? when i try to use it in a C program it fails on values larger than 8192.

```
    printf("create queue size: %lu\n", attr->mq_msgsize);
mqd_t mq = mq_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644, attr);
if (mq == (mqd_t)-1) {
    perror("mq_open error");
    exit(1);
} else {
    printf("mq_open successful\n");
}
//
```

i am setting the size to be larger but the program fails throws a size error

Comment: I've removed the "bash" Tag, since it seemed unrelated?!

Comment: I was using bash shell only reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value with the `sysctl` command.

e.g.

```
% cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max
8192

% sudo sysctl -w fs.mqueue.msgsize_max=16384
fs.mqueue.msgsize_max = 16384

% cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max  
16384
```

You can make this the default by adding a line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

e.g.

```
% grep -v '^#' /etc/sysctl.conf               
fs.mqueue.msgsize_max=16384
```

That entry will take effect on reboot or after running `sudo sysctl -p`